# How to read a network stream in scala?

Tags: macos, scala, networking, audio, streaming

How could I read a audio stream from the internet (e.g `http://70.36.96.24:13384/;stream.mp3`) and save its content to my local disk using Scala language?

I have tried to do it with:

```
val stream = new URL("http://70.36.96.24:13384/stream.mp3").openStream()
```

But it raises this exception:

```
java.io.IOException: Invalid Http response
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1342)
at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1037)
at .<init>(<console>:15)
at .<clinit>(<console>)
at .<init>(<console>:7)
at .<clinit>(<console>)
at $print(<console>)
    ...
```

The same command works with this other streaming url:e.g

`http://174-123-32-173.webnow.net.br/98fm.mp3`

**UPDATE: This code works perfectly on Linux, but not in Mac. Does anybody know the reason?**

**UPDATE2: Actually this code works on Java 6 but not in Java7. It doesnt matter the OS.**

Comment: I think the link is broken. You can try that with browser

Comment: What version of Java have you installed on both Linux and Mac ?

Comment: You are right: with Java 6 it works, with Java 7 it gives the error :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code doesn't work because the server isn't sending valid HTTP response. Notice this **HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 No headers, assuming HTTP/0.9**

```
$ wget -O- "http://70.36.96.24:13384/;stream.mp3" 
--2014-01-20 17:09:12--  http://70.36.96.24:13384/;stream.mp3
Connecting to 70.36.96.24:13384... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 No headers, assuming HTTP/0.9
Length: unspecified
Saving to: `STDOUT'

    [<=>                                                                                                                 ] 0           --.-K/s              ICY 200 OK
icy-notice1:<BR>This stream requires <a href="http://www.winamp.com/">Winamp</a><BR>
icy-notice2:SHOUTcast Distributed Network Audio Server/Linux v1.9.8<BR>
icy-name:Radio Brasileirissima
icy-genre:Musica Brasileira
icy-url:http://radiobrasileirissima.com.br
content-type:audio/mpeg
icy-pub:0
icy-br:64

....BINARY CONTENT SKIPPED....
```

You can still read the data by skipping the first few lines until the character sequence `\r\n\r\n`, where `icy-br:64` ends, and the actual AUDIO content begins. For this you can create a Socket, connect to it and sent a GET request to `/;stream.mp3' and read the data:

```
val timeout = 2000
val host = "70.36.96.24"
val port = 13384
val socket = new Socket
val endPoint = new InetSocketAddress(host, port)
socket.connect(endPoint, timeout);
// Here you send the GET request and read back the response.
// Every time you read the response, you have to skip
// the first few bytes until `\r\n\r\n`
```

**EDIT1**

NOTE: Your GET request must include extra newline for it to be an HTTP request

```
GET /;stream.mp3 HTTP/1.1
```

Here is the working example on the same URL:

```
  def socketurl = {
    val timeout = 2000
    val host = "70.36.96.24"
    val port = 13384
    val socket = new Socket
    val endPoint = new InetSocketAddress(host, port)
    socket.connect(endPoint, timeout);
    val (in, out) = (socket.getInputStream(), socket.getOutputStream())
    val httpRequest = "GET /;stream.mp3 HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n"
    val command = httpRequest.getBytes()
    println(httpRequest)
    out.write(command)

    var buf = Vector(0, 0, 0, 0)
    var c = in.read()
    var cont = true
    while (c != -1 && cont) {
      buf = buf.drop(1) :+ c
      print(c.toChar)
      if (buf(0) == '\r' && buf(1) == '\n' && buf(2) == '\r' && buf(3) == '\n') {
        cont = false
        println("Its a match")
      }
      c = in.read()
    }

    while (c != -1) {
      // keep buffering the data from here on!
    }
  }

// call the method 
socketurl
```

Comment: I have tried this:

val socket = new Socket
val endPoint = new InetSocketAddress(url.getHost(), url.getPort())
socket.connect(endPoint, 5000)
val stream = socket.getInputStream()
val path = url.getPath()
val command = ("GET " + path + "\n")
socket.getOutputStream().write(command.toCharArray().map(_.toByte))
socket.getOutputStream().flush()

but when I read from socket.getInputStream(), it is always empty....

Comment: Your GET request must include extra newline for it to be an HTTP request "GET /;stream.mp3 HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n"

Comment: @DanielCukier: I have updated the code. Please check. It should work for you now.